# Openshift doesn't copy docker container files to persistence volume

Tags: docker, openshift

I have created a Dockerfile that creates a Pentaho docker image with a persistence volume (using the VOLUME directive) in the biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/ directory. When running locally the Pentaho docker container, all the files contained in that directory are present and the persistence (adding plugins, project files etc etc) works fine. I have given a persistence volume to the same directory with the openshift template for the Pentaho but when creating an instance, the persistence volume that is allocated is empty and nothing is copied from the container image as I was expecting. Is there a way to do this through Openshift without having to export and copy the whole directory from the local docker container?

Comment: Persistent volumes under OpenShift are generally going to be on a remote node and not the node where your application is running as. They don't support the concept of copying data under where the volume is being mounted, into the volume.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Graham, I've managed to circumvent this problem by copying the needed files in a different directory and running a script to check for existence of these files before running Pentaho and then I copy them back to the volume if they do not exist. Pentaho is exporting the plugins into its system folder as far as I know and this was the main reason I had to do that.